# Manejo de fichero.txt

Tags: python

estoy tintando leer un archivo txt (que es un libro de historia) pero necesito definir una línea por un punto. Cada línea que lea, debe leerse hasta un punto (o "?" y pasar a la siguiente línea y leer hasta un punto o ("?") Alguna ayuda o ejemplo? Gracias

```
f = open('/cc/libro.txt')
datos = []
a = ""
lineas = f.readlines()
for linea in lineas:
    linea = linea.strip(\n")
    a+=linea
    b = a.split('. | ?',maxsplit=1)
    datos.append(b)
```

Comment: Haz un ciclo leyendo línea por línea y concatenandolas en una sola cadena. Tras agregar cada línea, usa `split('.', maxsplit=1)` sobre la cadena. Si retorna una lista de dos elementos, graba el primero y el segundo pasara a ser la cadena donde acumulas.

Comment: Quieres convertirlo en un fichero de una linea por cada frase?

Comment: @Francisco si porfavor, si tienes alguna guía de programación, me serviría mucho! Gracias

Comment: Buenas! He revisado tu pregunta y tengo algunas recomendaciones que hacer. 1 - Lee [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/) para que entiendas por que tu pregunta podría no ser bien recibida y terminar cerrada y/o con votos negativos. 2 - Si llega a ser necesario subir código, procura que sea un [mcve](/help/minimal-reproducible-example), no olvides formatear el código usando [markdown](/editing-help).

Comment: 3 - Ten en cuenta que nosotros no orientamos ni ofrecemos guias, ya que no encaja con el formato del sitio. Te recomiendo buscar otra pagina o entrar a nuestro [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com) si es que tenés suficiente reputación.

Comment: Hice una actualización de lo que estoy haciendo con mi código. Pero no consigo separar por "." o por "?".

Answer (score 0):

Prueba algo sencillo como ir leyendo carácter a carácter y cuando encuentras un punto saltas de linea.

```
f = open('/cc/libro.txt')
for linea in f:
    linea=linea.strip(" \n")#OK.Eliminas saltos de linea
    if (len(linea)>1):#Elimino linea en blanco(opcinal)
     for c in linea:
        if (c=='.' or c=='?'): print(c)
        else: print(c,end='')#sin salto de linea
```

Comment: funcionaría pero sucede que necesito unir frases que terminan por un "." o por "?" y que estas luego se conviertan en líneas.

Comment: Ya esta, se me paso reasignar la linea

Answer (score -1):

El tener el fichero partido por líneas no favorece el procesado. Sería más sencillo si lo tuvieras entero en una sola cadena, cosa fácil de conseguir si lo lees con `f.read()` en lugar de iterar por `f`.

En este caso puedes comenzar leyendo el fichero completo para después dividirlo por los caracteres que necesites (punto e interrogante). Pero para esto no puedes usar el método `.split()` normal de las cadenas, pues este no entiende que la cadena que le pasas especifica dos caracteres alternativos, sino que entiende que directamente esa cadena concreta `". | ?"` debe aparecer dentro del texto. Ya que no aparece no se realiza ninguna división.

Para hacer lo que quieres debes usar el módulo `re` (expresiones regulares) y utilizar `re.split()`, pero aquí aparecen nuevos problemas.

#### Primer intento

Para que mi código sea reproducible, en vez de leer los datos de un fichero los proporciono directamente dentro del código. En tu caso reemplazarías `texto = """..."""` por `texto = f.read()`.

```
texto = """
Esto es una prueba. A veces
una linea tiene varias frases, pero
otras veces una frase ocupa
varias líneas. ¿Se entiende? Espero que sí.
"""

import re

texto = texto.replace("\n", " ")  # Reemplazo retornos de carro por espacios
                                  # Según el caso puede ser preferible
                                  # reemplazarlo por "" la cadena vacía
datos = re.split(r"\.|\?", texto) # Dividir por frases
for frase in datos:
    print(frase.strip())          # E imprimir cada una
```

Esto produce el siguiente resultado, que está casi bien:

```
Esto es una prueba
A veces una linea tiene varias frases, pero otras veces una frase ocupa varias líneas
¿Se entiende
Espero que sí
```

¿Ves el fallo? Los caracteres por los que hemos dividido han desaparecido. Debería haber un punto al final de cada frase. Es especialmente evidente cuando falta el signo de interrogación.

#### Segundo intento

Si en la expresión regular que le pasas a `re.split()` incluyes un grupo de captura (paréntesis), entonces las expresiones que han hecho matching (en nuestro caso, el signo de puntuación al final de la frase) formarán también parte de los resultados.

Por desgracia no forman parte de la frase, sino que aparecen como elementos separados en la lista resultante:

```
datos = re.split(r"(\.|\?)", texto)
for frase in datos:
    print(frase.strip())
```

Ahora sale esto:

```
Esto es una prueba
.
A veces una linea tiene varias frases, pero otras veces una frase ocupa varias líneas
.
¿Se entiende
?
Espero que sí
.
```

#### Solución final

Lo que necesitamos entonces es procesar la lista resultante uniendo cada elemento con el siguiente. Una forma relativamente simple de hacerlo es juntar todos los elementos de la lista que ocupan posiciones pares (`datos[::2]`) con los que ocupan posiciones impares (`datos[1::2]`), usando `zip()` para ir sacando parejas formadas por un elemento de cada una de esas sublistas.

Esta idea por tanto queda así:

```
datos = re.split(r"(\.|\?)", texto)  # Esto es igual que antes
# Lo que cambia es la forma de procesar la lista
for frase, terminador in zip(datos[::2], datos[1::2]):
    print((frase+terminador).strip())
```

Resultado:

```
Esto es una prueba.
A veces una linea tiene varias frases, pero otras veces una frase ocupa varias líneas.
¿Se entiende?
Espero que sí.
```

## ADENDA: En caso de fichero muy grande

Si el fichero de entrada es muy grande, con millones de líneas, leerlo de una vez en memoria puede no ser posible (puede que se agote la memoria). En este caso habrá que recurrir a procesarlo línea por línea, con una idea similar a la que intentabas en tu código. No obstante, hay que corregir algunos problemas:

1. Usar `re.split()` en lugar de `str.split()` como ya hemos explicado
2. Usar grupos de captura en la expresión para capturar también si el terminador es punto o interrogante, como ya explicamos.
3. Aquí una corrección **importante**. La lista de resultados solo debe actualizarse cuando se haya detectado un terminador, es decir, cuando `re.split()` realmente haya partido algo. Si no, no se debe almacenar nada pues la frase de momento está incompleta.
4. Otra corrección **importante**, tras almacenar una frase en `datos`, la variable `a` debe reiniciarse para que no siga conteniendo lo que tenía de iteraciones anteriores (pues contendría la frase que acaba de ser procesada). El nuevo valor con que debe inicializarse es el de "el resto de la línea" (lo que quedó a la derecha del split).

Con estas ideas el código quedaría así:

```py
import re


f = open("prueba.txt")
a = ""
datos = []
for linea in f:
    linea = linea.replace("\n", " ")  # Cambiar retorno de carro por espacio
    a += linea
    b = re.split(r'(\.|\?)', a, maxsplit=1)
    if len(b)>2:  # Hubo partición?
        # En caso de que sí, almacenamos la parte izquierda en la lista
        # y la derecha reemplaza a lo que hubiera en `a`
        datos.append(b[0]+b[1])
        a = b[2]
    # En caso de que no haya habido partición, no hay que hacer nada.
    # No se añade frase nueva y `a` contiene lo que tenía de antes

# Al terminar el bucle, guardar lo que quedara tras el último split
datos.append(a)
f.close()

# Mostremos el resultado
for d in datos:
    print(d.strip())
```

Lo he comprobado sobre un fichero de prueba y funciona correctamente.

Comment: Me pareció que complicaste un problema sencillo

Comment: Resultó! Gracias!!!!